# Android listview loads images randomly when fast scrolled

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have seen similar questions to that, but mine is a little bit different:

I have a listview and each row has an imageview that loads a picture from url. Here is my adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder=null;

    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bestof_list_row, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.textviewRowNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_row_number);
        holder.imageviewUserPic = (RemoteImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_user_profile_pic);
        holder.textviewUsername = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_username);
        holder.textviewSubtextBold = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_subtext_bold);
        holder.textviewSubtextNotBold = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_subtext_not_bold);
    }else{          
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();         
    }       

    BestOfSubTabListItem item = getItem(position);  

    holder.textviewRowNumber.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));       
    holder.imageviewUserPic.setRemoteURI(item.getUserAvatarURL());
    holder.imageviewUserPic.loadImage();        
    holder.textviewUsername.setText(item.getUsername());    

    if(feedType == SocialFeedType.hero2){
        holder.textviewSubtextBold.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.textviewSubtextNotBold.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        holder.textviewSubtextBold.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.textviewSubtextNotBold.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);          
        holder.textviewSubtextBold.setText(item.getSubtextBold());          
        holder.textviewSubtextNotBold.setText(item.getSubTextNotBold());
    }

    convertView.setTag(holder);
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder{        
    public TextView textviewRowNumber;
    public RemoteImageView imageviewUserPic;
    public TextView textviewUsername;
    public TextView textviewSubtextBold;
    public TextView textviewSubtextNotBold;
}
```

When i scroll the listview fast, the images in imageviews change, they are put to wrong positions. One solution is removing the

```
if(convertview==null)
```

but this time, listview does not scroll smoothly. Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your loadImage() method?

Comment: @JaySoyer it is a long method and i am sure there is nothing wrong with it because if i do not care about performance issues and remove if(convertview==null) line, it loads the right images but scrolling becomes unsmooth

Comment: right.  I'll write my answer more conceptually then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're using convertviews, it means that listview will try to recycle views. In your case it means that the same view will be used in different positions in listview, and you're actually trying to load different images into same imageview. To prevent this, try using Picasso or Volley, they have this view reusing thing sorted out.

If you want to do it manually, you have to watch when your view goes off the screen and cancel image pulling request to make that imageview available to handle proper image for that position.

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i want to do it manually, so how can i watch when my view goes off the screen?

Comment: Here's the example how the guys at Google solved this.
https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/blob/master/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView.java
At line 202, they're watching when the view becomes detached from window, cancel the pending request (if there is one)

Comment: Thanks, i will have a look at it

Comment: Yeah, not sure how applicable that is for this case. That implies the OP creates a custom View to track when it's removed from the window.  There are easier ways to do it.